# Touch Calculator is not working properly

Tags: android

I am making a touch calculator. Whenever I run app, at the first time it works fine but after using 1 time when I try to press any number like 1,2,3,etc. It only presses one time. That is I can't write more than 1 figure number. Here's my code.

```
package bt4u.com.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,b19,b20;
float result;
float a;
float b;
float c;
Boolean get=false,error=false;

int d,count=0,q;
TextView tv,tv2;
String str;


int action;//0-add,1-sub,2-mul,3-div

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    b7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    b8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    b9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    b10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    b11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    b12=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    b13=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button13);
    b14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
    b15=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
    b16=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button16);
    b17=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);
    b18=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button18);
    b19=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button19);
    b20=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button20);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button1:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"9");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"8");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"7");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"6");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button5:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"5");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button6:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"4");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button7:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"3");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button8:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"2");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button9:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"1");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button10:
                    str=tv.getText().toString();
                    if (str.length()!=0) {
                        if (str.contains("."))
                            q=0;
                        else
                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + ".");
                        get=false;
                    }

                    break;
                case R.id.button11:
                    if (get)
                        tv.setText(null);
                    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"0");
                    b=Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button12:
                    switch (action){
                        case 0:
                            result=a+b;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            result=a-b;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            result=a*b;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            result=a/b;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (result==Math.ceil(result)) {
                        d = (int) result;
                        tv.setText("" + d);

                    }
                    else {
                        tv.setText("" + result);
                    }
                    tv2.setText(null);
                    get=true;
                    break;

                case R.id.button13:
                   try {
                       a = Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                   }
                   catch (NumberFormatException e){
                       error=true;
                   }
                    if (!error) {
                        tv2.setText(tv.getText() + "+");
                        action = 0;
                    }
                    error = false;
                    tv.setText(null);
                    break;

                case R.id.button14:
                    try {
                        a = Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        error=true;
                    }
                    if (!error) {
                        tv2.setText(tv.getText() + "*");
                        action = 2;
                    }
                    error = false;
                    tv.setText(null);
                    break;

                case R.id.button15:
                    try {
                        a = Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        error=true;
                    }
                    if (!error) {
                        tv2.setText(tv.getText() + "-");
                        action = 1;
                    }
                    error = false;
                    tv.setText(null);
                    break;

                case R.id.button16:
                    try {
                        a = Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        error=true;
                    }
                    if (!error) {
                        tv2.setText(tv.getText() + "/");
                        action = 3;
                    }
                    error = false;
                    tv.setText(null);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    b1.setOnClickListener(click);   b14.setOnClickListener(click);
    b2.setOnClickListener(click);   b15.setOnClickListener(click);
    b3.setOnClickListener(click);   b16.setOnClickListener(click);
    b4.setOnClickListener(click);   b17.setOnClickListener(click);
    b5.setOnClickListener(click);   b18.setOnClickListener(click);
    b6.setOnClickListener(click);   b19.setOnClickListener(click);
    b7.setOnClickListener(click);   b20.setOnClickListener(click);
    b8.setOnClickListener(click);   b13.setOnClickListener(click);
    b9.setOnClickListener(click);   b12.setOnClickListener(click);
    b10.setOnClickListener(click);  b11.setOnClickListener(click);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `get` and `error` variables as global variables and every time they are changed globally and may prevent further actions on next clicks . Define them as local variables inside the `onClick` method.

Comment: All actions are being performed in onCreate itself. So it doesn't matter if I declare them globally or locally. And get is showing if result is obtained or not. If it is obtained then next time if 1-9 numbers are pressed, they overwrite the result in text field. And error is only if string can't be converted to float(exception).

Comment: Do you re-create this activity on every action?

Comment: I have listeners on every button

Comment: When you do `get=false` e.g in button10, on next click ,non of the `if(get)` will work. you have to redefine `get` and `error` on every click not out of onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  case R.id.button12:
                            switch (action){
                                case 0:
                                    result=a+b;
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    result=a-b;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    result=a*b;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    result=a/b;
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (result==Math.ceil(result)) {
                                d = (int) result;
                                tv.setText("" + d);

                            }
                            else {
                                tv.setText("" + result);
                            }
                            tv2.setText(null);
                            get=false;
                            break;
```

//change only case R.id.button12.......i hope ,u can solve your problem.....